# How can I write xls and xlsx file (Excel file) from Dataset in spark with java?

Tags: excel, apache-spark, export-to-excel, xls

I want to write an Spark Dataset as an xls and xlsx (MS Excel) files using java.

So,

How can I write data into an excel sheet in spark?

I tried to generate the xls and xlsx file but, the report generated by csv files only

Comment: You can use this library - `https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel`

Answer (score 0):

given the *distributed* nature of the Spark framework the problem is that you are not going to write a single file but multiple files based on the number of partitions you have on the data, in any case if you want to write a single file you can always do a `coalesce(1)` before writing so as to reduce the data to a single partition, the problem then however will be that being a single file it will have a large size, and therefore you will hardly be able to read it with excel, if this is not your case since spark does not natively support writing in `.xls`, you can first write the file in `.csv` and then through a library convert it to Excel .xls file, I'll give you a resource to read:

https://blog.groupdocs.com/conversion/convert-csv-and-excel-xls-xlsx-in-java/